# Can a submanifold of a flat Manifold be curved?

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, tensors, submanifold

Consider the Minkowski space time

\begin{equation}
ds^2= -dt^2 + dx^2 + dy^2 + dz^2$
\end{equation}

Can we such a coordinate transformation on just the spatial part of the above metric (and not on the time part) such that the metric changes to something like

\begin{equation}
ds^2= -dt^2 + “ curved { } { } spatial  { } { } part”
\end{equation}

such that the original flat (Riemann Tensor vanishing indentically) 4d Manifold have a **curved( non vanishing Riemann Tensor)** 3d spatial submanifold.

1. Is such a case possible. Can a flat (Riemann Tensor vanishing indentically) manifold have a curved ( non vanishing Riemann Tensor) submanifold?
2. Can a flat 4d manifold be foliated with curved ( non vanishing Riemann Tensor) hypersurfaces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curvature is independent of coordinate system. If a metric is flat, it is flat. (For example, in $\Bbb R^2$, we have the standard metric $ds^2=dx^2+dy^2$; when we switch to polar coordinates, we have $ds^2=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2$. Christoffel symbols may be nonzero, but the curvature is still $0$.)

Of course flat spaces have submanifolds of all sorts of curvature. Just take any surfaces you wish sitting in $\Bbb R^3$; the same holds in all dimensions. It all then depends on the second fundamental form, which is *not* intrinsic to the submanifold. And you can certainly foliate flat space by non-flat hypersurfaces, yes.

Comment: Agree of course. It may be useful to add that the *components* of the Riemann tensor usually change in the appropriate way under a diffeomorphism (such as a change of chart). However if the components are zero with respect to a coordinate systems they vanish in any other since linear transformations fix 0.

Comment: Yeh I know curvature is independent of coordinates used. I just wanted to know whether a flat manifold's submanifold could be curved. Thanks I got that it can be. And similarly a curved manifold can have flat submanifold, is that right? And ( similarly) I think a curved manifold can be then foliated with flat hypersurfaces, is that right? It looks a bit strange that a curved manifold can be foliated ( made up) with flat hypersurfaces, so I just wanted to confirm.